# How does OS detect a crash of a process

Tags: c++, x86, crash, osdev

How does OS know that EIP is no longer a valid/legal instruction and that application has crashed? How does it know when to generate the crash dump data?

Comment: It knows because the CPU told it.

Comment: Typically, you get hardware (CPU, DMA, ...) interrupts (IRQ). These are handled by the OS directly. As the name tells, they interrupt the normal CPU processing and switch to some specific interrupt service routine (ISR). Within, OS can check which process was active when the interrupt occured (by inspecting thread scheduling table) and e. g. send a signal to (POSIX).

Comment: That's not the most common way to crash, but it is one way.

Comment: note: I assume this is about x86 because only x86 has an EIP register.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On an x86-compatible processor, when EIP points to a page which does not have read permission, a page that is not mapped, an invalid instruction, or when a valid instruction tries to access a memory page without permission, or a page that is not mapped, or a divide instruction sees that the denominator is zero, or an `INT` instruction is executed, or [a bunch of other things](https://wiki.osdev.org/Exceptions), it *raises an exception*. In the case of an exception occuring in protected mode when the current privilege level (CPL) is > 0, [the following things occur:](https://alex.dzyoba.com/blog/os-interrupts/)

- Loads the values for SS and ESP from a memory section called the [task state segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_state_segment).
- Pushes the values of SS, ESP, EFLAGS, CS and EIP onto the stack. The SS and ESP values are the previous ones, not the new ones from the TSS.
- Some exceptions also push an error code onto the stack.
- Gets the values for CS and EIP from the [interrupt descriptor table](https://wiki.osdev.org/IDT) and puts these values in CS and EIP.

Note that the kernel has set up these tables and segments in advance.

Then:

- The kernel decides what to do with the exception. This depends on the specific kernel. Usually, it decides to kill your program. On Linux, you can override this default using *signal handling* and on Windows you can override it using *Structured Exception Handling*.

*(This is not an exhaustive reference to x86 exception handling. This is a brief overview of the most common case.)*

Comment: Side note: Exceptions as used here have absolutely nothing to do with C++ exceptions. They occur beneath the C++ runtime and cannot be caught with a `try`/`catch` block.

Comment: Even in 64-bit mode, RSP is still loaded from the TSS.

Comment: Specifically, code fetch from a not-present or not-executable page will result in a `#PF` x86 hardware exception, handled by the kernel.  If the page-fault handler decides it was an *invalid* page fault, the kernel delivers a Unix SIGSEGV signal to the process, or the Windows equivalent. (Other kinds of HW page faults can be: hard (load the page from the swap/pagefile) or soft (allocate a new physical page of zeros to back this virtual page, or similar no-I/O-required mismatches between HW page tables and logical process memory)

Comment: The TSS isn't obsolete. It may have had some of its fields repurposed for the interrupt stack table. The TSS is still the only way to restrict individual IO port accesses through the IO port bitmap. What has been removed in long mode is hardware task switching which happened to rely on the TSS.

Comment: As for the statement *"Pushes the values of SS, ESP"*. This is true if there is a transition between rings in **protected mode**. If an exception occurs while at ring 0 the TSS isn't consulted and the current ring 0 stack pointer is used. The behaviour is different when in long mode.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I added the last line. Are you happy?

Answer (score 2):

The detailed answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59075911/15304 from @user253751 is there for you to know all that you may want to know.

A word of context might help though: processor usually proceeds to the next instruction after each instruction is over, but there are cases where it will suddenly start a completely unrelated instruction. This is called an **interrupt**, and is widely used to support device operations or get some code called at periodic intervals.

In an interrupt handler, we have to save the full processor state so that the interrupted code can be safely resumed after we're done with device-specific code.

The **hardware exception** mechanism used to know that a process is trying to do something that is impossible/invalid given the current configuration extensively borrows interrupts mechanisms, but it also has to take care of a context switch between (presumably) user-level code for the "faulty" process and kernel-level code that will handle the fault. That context switch is the reason why we see stack pointers re-loaded and task state segment involved in the description of hardware exceptions that have much simpler definitions (e.g. exectue instruction at address 0xfffff000) on other architectures.

Note that having a hardware exception doesn't necessarily means that the process crashed. The exception handler in the kernel will usually have to compare some information (what address we tried to access, what object is mapped at this address, etc.) and either does useful job (bring one more page of a mapped file into memory) and resume the process, or calls it an invalid access.

Comment: `hardware exception` would probably be better described as a `cpu exception` . A hardware exception could suggest some external event outside the CPU like some kind of Non Maskable Interrupt etc signalling some kind of hardware issue.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I'm afraid we'll have to pick our own terminology here, as [ https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3a-part-1-manual.pdf#G11.1553 ] simply calls them "exceptions", ignoring potential conflict with software constructs such as C++ exceptions. I picked "hardware" to contrast them with those purely-software things. "CPU" could work too, although -- to my knowledge -- no other piece of hardware could create one. (NMI is still called "interrupt" in the exception & interrupts table)